# Unable to install Pyperclip in Spyder Python 3.7

Tags: python, pyperclip

Unable to install Pyperclip in Spyder Python 3.7.
Though pip is installed successfully. I am facing problem with Pyperclip module only. Below is the screenshot[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with spyder

Comment: Seems like your internet is just broken

Comment: mousetail Thanks a lot. My office network was probably blocking it.

With open network it allowed me to install.

Answer (score 0):

mousetail yes you were right My office network was probably blocking it.

With open network it allowed me to install.